# Determine if service center can access my files by bypassing admin privileges

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, administrator

I had to send my laptop at the repair centre for some issues it was having. It is known before-hand that it will need to be dis-assembled.

I have an administrator account and a guest account. I asked the centre to use the guest account if they needed to start the laptop for troubleshooting. I have blocked access to my personal files in the guest account.

Now, I know that he cannot open the admin account on my laptop. Also, if he tries to boot into another laptop through my hard-drive, I reckon even then he shouldn't have access to my personal files.

But what if he opens my hard-drive on a different computer as he would normally open a flash drive? Will he then have access? From how I see it, since all the software (and hence admin safeguards) are coded within the hard-drive, it shouldn't be accessible from any of the above methods.

If the question is silly, I would like to know what obvious piece of information I am missing.

PS. it's not a duplicate as i didn't find any question of this type that also referred to admin privileges.

Comment: If you're downvoting, you ought to tell why. I can't "imagine" what issues you might be having with my question.

Comment: My question is whether he will be able to access my personal files. Wait, i'll change the heading.

Comment: "I reckon even then he shouldn't have access to my personal files."  - What makes you think that?  If you are worried you should use full disk encryption. Your follow-up question, after you making a statement like this, does not make much sense.  Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

It is the operating system that mediates access to files based on permissions.

If someone else has access to your hard disk, they can access any of the files that aren't encrypted.

Permissions themselves do not do anything to prevent access to files, they just indicate to the operating system which accounts should be able to view the files.  The OS can ignore this or honour it, but there is always an administration account that can override.

Answer (score 2):

He could use a livecd or linux install that completely ignores windows file permissions. You could do it with another windows box but this would get messy depending on what he's doing.

In any case getting around a password or [changing](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) it is *trivial* if you know what you're doing. Its even possible to copy out the file where the password is encoded and to crack it at leisure. There's an old [superuser blog post](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/03/01/kon-boot-getting-into-a-clients-computer-without-using-a-portal-gun/) that goes into this in detail

Your windows password isn't really protection against a determined *skilled* hacker, especially since in the scenario full disk encryption (which would be the only way to protect against an attacker with physical access) wouldn't help.

Without knowing what the initial issue is, its possible that the repair center might *need* admin access for troubleshooting. In short, this scenario seems a bit unfair to the person repairing the system. Access to logs and such would be difficult for example.

Depending on what you're worried about

1. Make a full disk image (so you can restore it when you get back... clean system!). Also protects your data should something go wrong during the repair.
2. Remove anything sensitive from the laptop (to keep stuff from getting out). Maybe even restore to a factory image (but that would hide any software issues I guess). Do backup first.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running Win7 Pro or higher, you can use a feature called EFS (Encrypting File System) to protect your sensitive files. To turn on EFS for a file, or for all contents of a directory, right-click the file or directory, select Properties, under Attributes click Advanced, and then check the box for "Encrypt contents to secure data". Hit OK, then hit OK (or Apply) on the Properties window, and then (if it's a directory) choose the option "Apply changes to this folder, subfolders, and files" and hit OK again.

Note that EFS protects the encryption key using your password. This means the data can be decrypted if the attacker is in possession of your hard disk (or a copy of it) and can figure out your password. As @Journeyman Geek says, there are easy-to-use tools that extract a Windows password and attempt to crack it at leisure. If you want the password to be safe, it needs to be extremely long and complex. You could change it before sending it in (and write down the new password, but don't send that of course) and then change it again when you get the machine back. At that point, you can decrypt the files (if you want to; it's actually OK to leave them encrypted). Technically that's not perfect safety - since you probably will need to give the support people Admin access, they will be able to install a rootkit on your drive that steals your password (or the encrypted files) as soon as you log in - but that's wayyyy more intense (and criminal) than just reading through your personal folders or even using a password brute-forcing program. I wouldn't be too worried.

If you don't have the option to use EFS, or if you want to secure your files with encryption that they can't possibly get off your machine, you can encrypt the files using something like GPG (GNU Privacy Guard, the open-source version of PGP or Pretty Good Privacy). Unlike EFS, GPG can't do in-place transparent encryption - it just creates an encrypted copy of the file, after which the original can be deleted, and you have to manually decrypt the file when you want to access it again - but you can do it with keys that are never stored on the PC at all and therefore there's no way for attackers to get them even if they take a full image of your hard drive (although they could still put a rootkit on the drive before sending it back to you, and then wait for you to decrypt the files yourself).